# undeclared identifier

Tags: c++, visual-c++

Need a second set of eyes. I am getting the following error:

```
1>c:\users\thom\documents\cworkspace\barnaby\barnaby\timezone.h(15): error C2065: 'TransitionTimeInfo' : undeclared identifier
```

Here is the line of code on which I'm receiving the error:

```
Timezone(std::vector<LeapSecondsInfo> &leapSecondsVector, std::vector<unsigned char> &localTimeTypes, std::vector<P6::UINT8>  &stdWallIndicators, &std::vector<unsigned long> &transitionTimes, std::vector<TransitionTimeInfo> &transitionTimesInfo, std::vector<P6::UINT8> &utcLocalIndicators){
```

This is the line for the constructor for my class. This file has the following include:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
```

And here is the salient part of the stdafx.h:

```
#include "targetver.h"
#include "barnaby.h"
#include "LeapSecondsInfo.h"
#include "p6types.h"
#include "Timezone.h"
#include "TransitionTimeInfo.h"
```

And here is TransitionTimeInfo.h:

```
class TransitionTimeInfo
{
public:
    TransitionTimeInfo(long gmtOffset, bool daylightSavings, unsigned int abbreviationIndex){
        setAbbreviationIndex(abbreviationIndex);
        setDaylightSavings(daylightSavings);
        setGmtOffset(gmtOffset);
    }
    virtual ~TransitionTimeInfo(void) {};

    unsigned int getAbbreviationIndex(){
        return abbreviationIndex;
    }

    void setAbbreviationIndex(unsigned int newVal){
        abbreviationIndex = newVal;
    }

    bool isDaylightSavings(){
        return daylightSavings;
    }

    void setDaylightSavings(bool newVal){
        daylightSavings = newVal;
    }

    long getGmtOffset(){
        return gmtOffset;
    }

    void setGmtOffset(long newVal){
        gmtOffset = newVal;
    }
private:
    long            gmtOffset;
    bool            daylightSavings;
    unsigned int    abbreviationIndex;
};
```

What's more, if I click on the type name and hit F12 (Visual C++) it takes me to this file.

Any ideas?

Thanks.

Comment: Stupid question: I don't understand this bit `std::vector<P6::UINT8> &std::vector<unsigned long> &transitionTimes` - that's `typeA &typeB &argName`? What does that represent, a vector of vectors? (Actually I'm thinking now it's a typo, there should be another arg name and a comma in there, I'm just checking I still remember my C++)

Comment: Yeah, typo. Sorry. good catch!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Change the order of includes:

```
#include "TransitionTimeInfo.h"
#include "Timezone.h"
```

The `Timezone.h` uses `TransitionTimeInfo` but the "TransitionTimeInfo.h" is included after it.

Ideally, You should always follow the rule:

**Each file should include all the header files it needs and not rely on them getting included indirectly through some other files.**

So, You should include "TransitionTimeInfo.h" in "Timezone.h".

Comment: Better yet, fix the inclusions so that each file stands on its own. (E.g. include `TransitionTimeInfo.h` in `Timezone.h`.)

Comment: Yeah, well, when in Rome. I'm building a DLL and this is the Microsoft Recommendation. I'm trying to be compliant. :(